# Without using for each loop container in ssis , I have to dump one folder that contains several files in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

There is one folder that contains 4 csv files , I have to dump it to sql server without using foreach loop container. How to do that?

Comment: Is it always the same names and number of files?

Comment: What is the reason cannot use each loop, bother to tell? So we can better understand what might be solution.

Comment: Files might change in the folder that depends on daily basis.

Comment: reason - nothing specific but there is another way to do this task by using script task! But I am not sure how to do that!

Comment: @PujaMishra i edited my answer , take a look

Comment: @PujaMishra thx for accepting my answer, it is good to read the [Tour page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more on accepting and upvoting answer. And to get a informed badge. Helpful answers must be upvoted.in this question the 3 answers provided are helpful and must be upvoted even if they are not detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

the simplest way is to import these files to sql using an `Execute sql Task`, but first you should build the whole sql command using a `Script Task`

Just follow this article to learn more on import csv to SQL:

- [SQL SERVER – Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using Bulk Insert – Load Comma Delimited File Into SQL Server](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

### Example

Assuming that we have the following 4 flat files in the Directory `C:\New\` with the following structure:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
bla,bla,bla
bla,bla,bla
```

1. First of all we have to add an `Execute Sql Task` to create the Sql Table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE TBLTEMP(COL1 VARCHAR(50),
                    COL2 VARCHAR(50),
                    COL3 VARCHAR(50))
   ```
2. Second we have to add Variable `@[User::strQuery]` of type string
3. Add a Script Task and select `@[User::strQuery]` as ReadWrite Variable
4. In The Script Task Write The Following Code:

   ```
   Public Sub Main()

       Dim strQuery As String = ""

       For Each strFile As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\New", "*.csv", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

           strQuery &= vbNewLine &
               "BULK INSERT [TBLTEMP] " & vbNewLine &
               " FROM '" & strFile & "' WITH" & vbNewLine &
               "(FIELDTERMINATOR = ','," & vbNewLine &
               "ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' ) " & vbNewLine &
               "GO" & vbNewLine

       Next


       Dts.Variables.Item("User::strQuery").Value = strQuery

       Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
   End Sub
   ```
5. Add an `Execute Sql Task` and use `@[User::strQuery]` as SqlCommand (Select Source Type = Variable)

**ScreenShots**

*First Execute Sql Task*

[image]

*Script Task*

[image]

*Second Execute Sql Task*

[image]

*Whole Package*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a Script task.

The script task would use the file system object to loop through the files in the folder, read them row by row, and insert the rows into the database.

Comment: @PujaMishra why accepting this answer if it doesn't solved your problem, you have to accept an answer that solved your issue. also this not an answer , it must be a comment :)

Comment: @PujaMishra, what is the gain not to use SSIS for each loop container vs use script task loop/read each file?

Comment: @Wendy I assume the question is academic.  It sounds like homework to me.

Comment: Script task better on handling if file exists.  Let's say you wait for 10 files, only when all files arrived, then you start loading. Data flow can do a better job loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest answer. Create a dataflow for each csv file.

*My guess is that the files aren't the same if you aren't using a foreach.*

Comment: Files are same , there is another way to handle this by using script task. Creating DFT for each csv ,not a good approach ,very lengthy in case we have so many files.